# edge policy IntranetFileLinksEnabled enabled does not open file

Tags: microsoft-edge, intranet, gpo, microsoft-edge-chromium, file-link

Last week [Edge 95 was released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-relnote-stable-channel) bringing the new and long awaiting [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) policy.

Testing this I encounter a different behavior than expected. 
Having the following test html file with links on a web-server e.g. `http://demohost/` and having `http://demohost/` added as "local-intranet" site.
Clicking the file links on e.g. `http://demohost/test.html`, I expect the file to be opened directly (e.g. docx in MS Word, pdf in Acrobat Reader, txt in Notepad ...):

```
<a href="file://power/share/demo.txt">file://power/share/demo.txt</a><br/>
<a href="file://power/share/demo.docx">file://power/share/demo.docx</a><br/>
<a href="file://power/share/demo.pdf">file://power/share/demo.pdf</a><br/>
<a href="file://power/share/demo.html">file://power/share/demo.html</a><br/>
```

But instead the share is opened in the explorer and the file is selected, but not opened.
e.g. demo.docx or demo.pdf:

[image]

Are there any additional policies I have to configure to establish a similar behavior as the Internet Explorer used to have? (actually opening the files)

Result of [edge://policy/](http://edge://policy/):
[image]

EDIT: I tried out a lot of different GPO settings in "Microsoft Edge" and "Internet Explorer" category, e.g. `PopupsAllowedForUrls`. Didn't find a solution.

EDIT2: Also file links to a drive e.g. `file://D:/temp/demo.txt` are blocked completely.

Comment: For your issue, I have done many tests, but failed to reproduce your issue. I think there may be some problems with my test. I recommend you to send feedback to the relevant team, just press `Alt+ Shift+ i` to edit the content and send it.

Comment: How did you fail to reproduce the issue, was the file blocked or was it opened directly. What Version of Edge did you use? Do you run your test html file on a web-server or just open it from the local filesystem?

Comment: I tried to open it in the local file system, but the file was blocked in Edge.

Comment: ok, the html page containing the links needs to be running on a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design and for sure because of security purposes.

If you read the [policy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) carefully, it is really good
documented what is going to happen:

> This setting allows file URL links to intranet zone files from
> intranet zone HTTPS websites **to open Windows File Explorer** for that
> file or directory.
>
> If you enable this policy, intranet zone file URL links originating
> from intranet zone HTTPS pages **will open Windows File Explorer to the
> parent directory of the file and select the file**. Intranet zone
> directory URL links originating from intranet zone HTTPS pages **will
> open Windows File Explorer to the directory with no items in the
> directory selected**.
>
> If you disable or don't configure this policy, file URL links will not
> open.
>
> Microsoft Edge uses the definition of intranet zone as configured for
> Internet Explorer. Note that https://localhost/ is specifically
> blocked as an exception of allowed intranet zone host, while loopback
> addresses (127.0.0.*, [::1]) are considered internet zone by default.
>
> Users may opt out of prompts on a per-protocol/per-site basis unless
> the ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox policy is disabled.

Comment: I can see the security issue if the link is on a file, but for links on a directory? Open the parent directory, which is not necessarily readable? I fail to see the pros.

Comment: @kagmole When it comes to security, even a new threat vector is a thing. (every new feature introduces possibilities)

Comment: Since Edge 100, link on a directory now opens it as expected instead of the parent folder.

Comment: There is no behavior change other than an additional security dialog to open the File Explorer. The file link opens in the parent folder of the file specified.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a file link to a **directory**, not a file. The policy documentation changed as well (you can see the change in the link of your answer). Links on directories now correctly open the directory and not the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the updated documentation. I did not recognize any behavior change, but the documentation is much clearer now.